# jquery - autocomplete url

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using jQuery autocomplete in my web application. I followed this http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp When it sends the suggestion request it sending to the different url not the one I've given in `$.ajax()` url

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$("#add-keywords").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        var q = $("#add-keywords").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "keywords_suggestions/",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                  query: q
            }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        }
});
```

I'm using Django for server side scripting. It must actually want to request to this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/keywords_suggestions` But it requesting to this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/information/?query=web` Why is it so?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found a solution to this? I ran into the same problem.

Comment: Not the main issue but you're referring to log(), probably instead of console.log()

Answer (score 0):

Either it doesn't like the URL, or the given one doesn't exist anyways try to put a `/` before the url url: "`/keywords_suggestions/`" maybe this will help.

Otherwhise take a look if you have a different autocomplete on the same site if it get's triggered unintentionally by your function - as you said it's going to a different url then specified `->` try to find out what kind of url it is - and how it could possibly be redirected there.

Comment: No it's not working. I have no other autocomplete plugins in that page.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and resolved it by loading the latest jquery and jqueryUI files.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Earlier i was using only the autocomplete.min.js taken up from some website. May be that was the problem